# Проблема с Log4Net

Tags: c#, log4net

Скачал dll, подключил ее, директивы `using` как в примерах сделал. Вот конкретнее.

```
using log4net;    
using log4net.Config;
 ... 
public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program)); 
log.Info("eeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
```

Выдает вот это:

> Ошибка    21  Не удалось найти имя типа или пространства имен "log4net" (пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку?)
>
> C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\проект\Новая папка\kitay\kitay\Program.cs   6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое делали??
В App.Config пишем :

```
  <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="log-file.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Потом нужно вызвать метод Configure:

```
  static void Main()
{
      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
...
```

Comment: Конфигурационный файл есть. У меня есть скачанный проект, который прекрасно работает. Все беру с него. Тут не работает. В таком конфиге привязки к проекту конкретному нет, не знаю в чем причина.

Comment: Добавил log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); но он не видит log4net в текущем контексте

Comment: If Visual studio doesn't recognize log4net. Configure your     project like this:

    Visual Studio -> project -> project name properties -> target     framework -> .net Framework (not client)

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду? Я зашел туда, там есть только .net Framework 4 и тд.
Просто .net Framework  нету

Comment: Поменял Framework 4 Client Profile на .net Framework 4 Все заработало. Сегодня Вы спасли немалую часть моих нервов)